# Insert entity in JScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2011

In Mscrm 2011 I've added a custom button on the ribbon.

What I like to do is when the user push the button, a new record of an entity should be created in JScript, for example a new contact.

How can I do this in JScript? I'm quite new to JScript and CRM, so I don't have a clue and the results from Google are unclear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the SDK for the sample using the REST ODATA endpoint in javascript

Sample: Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete (CRUD) using the REST endpoint with JScript and JQuery

seach the SDK directories for the file CrmODataJQuery.js